# iOS camera lens Position change values

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am working on camera app which supports above iOS8.Due to my requirement i need to change the lens values.(Not focus point).My lens position values are something like 36 mm,45 mm and so on.How can i apply these values to camera or any other default values available? I am using AVCapture for taking photos. Any help would be thankful.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the angle of view, i.e. crop the image?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question because when you move the lens position, you are in fact changing camera's focal point (camera's optical properties), not the same thing as focus point of interest witch is the area of interest in the the image.

So, to change the lens position you can do it with this method:

```
- (void)setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:(float)lensPosition 
                         completionHandler:(void (^)(CMTime syncTime))handler
```

You can find it in `AVCaptureDevice` class reference (this will be the device you selected has camera for your app). *lensPosition* value it's beetween 0 and 1, it's a relative positioning system, so you can't use those values (36mm and 45mm).